# How to stop and start app delegate timer using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I have in my app login and logout process here I am facing so many problem with background timer services process. Below code I am maintaining for notification and JSON service background while applicationDidBecomeActive.

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    checkJSONtimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(updateJSON) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Problems below

1. Before login, timer activity started
2. After logout, timer activity not stopping
3. If I commented above timer after background to come active state,
   then timer not working
4. Every time without `logout` , cleared `background app` running again
   open I can go from `login`

`FYI :` Above timer selector method I am maintaining below three places

```
1. application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
2. applicationDidBecomeActive
3. applicationDidEnterBackground
```

How to solve above problems. Please help me!

Comment: do you stop the timer with `invalidate`?

Comment: when? no timer not stoping. moreover I am maintaining login action event into home screen, timer everything implemented into app delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Before login, timer activity started

> For that you have to make a check whether the user is log-in the app or not.For example
>
> ```
> -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
>     if(isUserLogedIn) {
>       checkJSONtimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(updateJSON) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
>       NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
>       application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
>    }
> }
> ```

2. After logout, timer activity not stopping

   > For that, make a Notification which will trigger when the user log-out from the app.When the notification triggers the invalidate the timer.[myTimer inValidate].
3. If I commented above timer after background to come active state, then timer not working

   > No need to comment the timer.Just manage the timer affectively.
4. Every time without logout , cleared background app running again open I can go from login.

   > For that you have to manage the User session in NSUserDefaults.Check the value, if the value is not null, the log-in user automatically.

Comment: Awesome! Give me any sample code for login and logout process session with NSUserDefaults method @Rajatp

Comment: If you are log in the app using server based authentication, then while you successfully log in the app, store all the information which you got from server to NSUserDefaults, something like                                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myInformation forKey:@"userSession"], now when your app launched again then check this value, if it is not null then log in user automatically to app.When user logout then make the NSUserDefaults value nil, like [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"userSession"].Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes I did for that I am asking sample code. It will help to others. how to put If statement for that validation?@Rajatp

Comment: NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSObject * object = [prefs objectForKey:@"your_particular_key"];
if(object != nil){
   //object is there
}

Comment: Its simple, just check like this  
   if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"]!=nil) {
            //your code here
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the timer you can use something like this:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

[appDelegate.checkJSONtimer invalidate]
```

Comment: where I want to paste this one?